# Incompatible types when assigning to type char[] from type int

Tags: c, struct

let say I have this struct

```
 struct person {
   char last_name [10];
 };
typedef struct person Person;
```

And I fill this struct-object with a certain name

```
Person p;
Person *ptrPerson = &p;
strcpy(ptrPerson->last_name, "Johnson");
```

And then I put this name in an array of type Person ... put in the first position

```
Person queue[10];
queue[0] = *ptrPerson;
```

So far so good. But how do I nullify the arraypostion after that - or at least put a character "-" there instead:

```
queue[0].last_name = "-";
```

I get the following compilation error:

***error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[10]' from type 'int'***

Comment: Where is declared variable first_name ?

Comment: `first_name` is not a member of `Person`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queue[0].last_name = "-";` is trying to assign the address returned by `"-"`.

Use `strcpy (queue[0].last_name ,"-");`

Answer (score 1):

Either keep track of which entries are used and which are "free". Or if you want to clear the whole structure you can use e.g. [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). Or to copy a string you already are using `strcpy` at one place, why don't you use it at the other?